# Get keys of json data of certain level

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I got parsed data object. The data is retuned by backend as JSON and has been parsed as data object in react-native client.

```
{
    "level1-key1": "value1",
    "level1-key2": "value2",
    "level1-key3": "value3",
    "level1-key4":{
        "level2-k1": "val1",
        "level2-k2": {
             "level3-k1": "v1",
             "level3-k2": "v2",
             "level3-k3": "v3"
        }
     }
}
```

I would like to get different level keys as an array of strings, i.e. I want to get level 2 keys, which are `["level2-k1", "level2-k2"]`.

I want to get level 3 keys, which are

```
["level3-k1", "level3-k2", "level3-k3"]
```

How achieve it?

Comment: Is there always one nested leaf? or it can be like `level1-key3:{level2-k3: "v6"}`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should solve your problem

```js
const data = {
  'level1-key1': 'value1',
  'level1-key2': 'value2',
  'level1-key3': 'value3',
  'level1-key4': {
    'level2-k1': 'val1',
    'level2-k2': {
      'level3-k1': 'v1',
      'level3-k2': 'v2',
      'level3-k3': 'v3',
    },
  },
};

const isObject = (v) => typeof v === 'object' && v != null;

const getAllKeysByLevel = (data, level) => {
  let levelObjects = [data];

  for (let i = 0; i < level; i += 1) {
    levelObjects = levelObjects.flatMap((item) =>
      isObject(item) ? Object.values(item) : [],
    );
  }

  return levelObjects.flatMap((item) =>
    isObject(item) ? Object.keys(item) : [],
  );
};

const level1 = getAllKeysByLevel(data, 0);
const level2 = getAllKeysByLevel(data, 1);
const level3 = getAllKeysByLevel(data, 2);

console.log(' --- xdebug ', {
  level1,
  level2,
  level3,
});

/*
--- xdebug  {
    level1: [ 'level1-key1', 'level1-key2', 'level1-key3', 'level1-key4' ],
    level2: [ 'level2-k1', 'level2-k2' ],
    level3: [ 'level3-k1', 'level3-k2', 'level3-k3' ]
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work, finding out the leaf nodes and check if it is an object and repeat it till the end.

```js
const data = {
    "level1-key1": "value1",
    "level1-key2": "value2",
    "level1-key3": "value3",
    "level1-key4":{
        "level2-k1": "val1",
        "level2-k2": {
             "level3-k1": "v1",
             "level3-k2": "v2",
             "level3-k3": "v3"
        }
     }
}

function findLevels(data){
    let counter = 1;
    let final = {};
    getKeys(data)
    function getKeys(obj){
        let k = Object.keys(obj);
        final[counter] = k;
        // scan if there is any object
        for(let i = 0; i < k.length; i++){
            if(typeof obj[k[i]] === "object"){
                counter += 1;
                getKeys(obj[k[i]])
            }
        }
    }
    return final;
}

const result = findLevels(data);
console.log(result)
```